# Django web-push "Reverse for 'save_webpush_info'"

Tags: django, web-push

I've installed **django-webpush** in my project and put
`{% webpush_header %}` in the `<head>` part of my HTML template as instructed, however I am getting an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'save_webpush_info' not found. 'save_webpush_info' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I use `{% load webpush_notifications %}` above that and have added webpush as part of the INSTALLED_APPS, along with the following in urls.py:

```
url(r'^webpush/', include('webpush.urls')),
```

https://github.com/safwanrahman/django-webpush

Comment: Do you have something like `app_name = "<something>"` in your `urls.py`?

Comment: I do... good point! Is there a way to ignore that app_name context specifically for this url/path?

Comment: Perhaps include them in your project level urls, or put the apps patterns and this pattern in different lists and include both in the `urlpatterns` list and pass the namespace to `include`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your urls.py is something like so:

```
app_name = '<something>'

urlpatterns = [
    # Other patterns
    url(r'^webpush/', include('webpush.urls')),
]
```

Instead do something like:

```
from django.urls import path


app_urls = (
    [
        # Other patterns
    ],
    '<something>' # Specifying app_namespace
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(app_urls)),
    path('webpush/', include('webpush.urls')),
]
```

**Edit**: As these are urls of a third party package it would be best to put them in your projects top - level `urls.py`. If you want the paths to be similar to this apps:

```
path('path/to/some_app/webpush/', include('webpush.urls')),
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Unfortunately, I tried that but still getting an error: *django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead*

which is very strange because an app_name shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: @jjwood1600 I had edited the answer. Did you use this one? If you notice we have passed a 2-tuple here.

Comment: Yes, I am using the most up to date version with a 2-tuple so not sure what's going on! Really appreciate your help so far

Comment: @jjwood1600 did you remove `app_name = '<something>'` that you had written previously?

Comment: Yes, everything should be exactly the same as your answer. I'll figure it out, don't worry - thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @jjwood1600 Are you including these urls somewhere else with a namespace?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229462/discussion-between-jjwood1600-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).